# In java would you put a scoring value as parameters in a game?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

In class we are learning about inheritance, calling and creating methods and constructors. We had to design a simple game using dice and were instructed to create a super class with two attributes, name and score. When creating the constructor for the class would you insert the variable for keeping score as a parameter?
I ask this because when we call on the constructor in the sub-class we have to have score as an argument which doesn't make sense to me since its already set to 0.

```
public class Players
{
    private String name = null;
    private int score = 0;

    public Players(String name, int score)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.score = score;
    }

    public Players(String name)
    {
       this(name, 0);
    }   

    public String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
       return score;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public void setScore(int score)
    {
       this.score = score;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You're probably better off with a code example.

Comment: perhaps the score parameter determines the winner, and is not the running total of score in the game?? This way a game A could determine a winner at a score of say 5 and another "longer" game B determines a winner with a score of 50?? i'm just guessing... a code example would help clarify

Comment: @notyou thanks, its my first question and I wasn't sure how to do it and if I needed to.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz the teacher wasn't specific about the use of the score, i just presumed it was for keeping track of who won the round of for example tic tac toe or some sort of dice game. I edited code in the question though, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your application, you are only instantiating an instance of this class with a score of 0, then it will not be necessary to add score as a parameter to the constructor. You can just set score = 0 within the constructor body.  Although, you can also choose to overload the constructor method, writing another constructor that will set the score to something other than 0, depending on the args provided in the call.

Comment: have it set to 0 in the constructor makes sense to me thanks.The example given by the teacher had an overloaded constructor with score set to 0 as a default but that seems to me making the first constructor as redundant since you wont ever add score as an argument if you just have it as 0 as a default and then increment whenever it is needed to be increased.